# Selenium with Java - element not found

Tags: java, selenium, testing, automation

I am trying to write a test for automation that logs in on a website, which works with a redirect from an e-identify system. We currently mock the e-identify part.

What the test is supposed to do: Go to a website, log in, verify that user is logged in by checking an element on the page after logging in.

The test is trying to find a specific element after having logged in, to verify that it has logged in.
The test does not seem to be able to find the specified element, even though I can find the element when I go to the website. This is the element that cannot be found: (By.id("ingelogdeGebruiker"). It gets a timeout after looking for the element for 5 seconds. I have tried increasing the wait to 50 seconds, because I wanted to know if it just takes longer than 5 seconds to find the element. After 50 seconds it was still not found.

The login code:

```
public void login(Website website) {
        WebElement naarInlogknop = ldriver.findElement(By.id("inloggenKnop"));
        if (naarInlogknop == null) {
            clickLogoutKnop();
        }
        naarInlogknop.click();
        WebElement inlogknopEherkenning = ldriver.findElement(By.id("inloggenEHerkenning"));
        assertNotNull("Er is geen inlogknop voor eHerkenning op de pagina, terwijl die wel verwacht wordt.",
                inlogknopEherkenning);
        assertTrue(inlogknopEherkenning.isDisplayed());
        inlogknopEherkenning.click();
        ldriver.navigate().to(website.getUrl() + "/producer/vaststelling/files");
        WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(ldriver, 5);
        wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.id("ingelogdeGebruiker")));
        WebElement controleElement = ldriver.findElement(By.id("ingelogdeGebruiker"));
        assertNotNull("Na inloggen is de ingelogde gebruiker niet zichtbaar, terwijl dat wel verwacht wordt.",
                controleElement);
```

Thank you in advance.

UPDATE as per Debanjan28's request:

HTML of the element:

```
<a _ngcontent-gnk-c73="" tabindex="0" id="ingelogdeGebruiker" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" class="nav-link dropdown-toggle"><span _ngcontent-gnk-c73="" class="h5 icon icon-user mx-1"></span> 88228822 <span _ngcontent-gnk-c73="" class="ml-2 icon icon-chevron-down"></span></a>
```

Comment: It is difficult to judge without knowing the structure of the webpage. Have you tried using [`presenceOfElementLocated`](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/ExpectedConditions.html#presenceOfElementLocated(org.openqa.selenium.By)) to work around the element possibly not being visible?

Comment: Update the question with the relevant HTML of the element

Comment: @DebanjanB Edited the question with the relevant HTML of the element.

Comment: @kidney Tried as well, did not work. Same result, not able to find element.

Comment: This look likes an angular element and some of them are difficult to locate by Webdriver. At times introducing proper waits helps or else you try using ng webdriver.